# No Panel when I boot-up, after running "Remember Currently Running Applications"

Tags: 10.04, gnome-panel

As the question's title says, I have no Panel when I  re-start Ubuntu.  It happened after I selected *"Automatically remember running applications when logging off"* in System-- Preferences-- Startup Applications-- Options.

I can manually start it via `(gnome-panel &)` in the Terminal, bur aside from that, it refuses to start iself. (I've since disabled  "Remember Applications wehen logging off")

How can I get it working normally again?

Comment: Try typing the following in your terminal 
`gconftool-2 --shutdown`
`rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel`
`pkill gnome-panel`

Comment: I tried your suggestion (after making a backup of the ~/.gconf) .. and it is still not working... I think the problem may lie with *"Remember Currently Running Applications”*, because 2 Nautilus windows popped up on re-boot... (and I have another strange thing happening today re: logging on to AskUbuntu..(co-incidentally(?)"... but that may be something else ) ...

Comment: PS. (to rule out any connection...) The AskUbuntu Openid login-validation problem, is related to the No-Script plugin for Firefox . I set up NoScript (with an identical profile) in a VM and I got the same "hanging on validation" problem.. I think the latest NoScript came out only a day or so ago ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe one day it will become clear what is causing this failure of the Panel to auto-start, but for *today*, I've arrived at an effective workaround.

It is simply a matter of adding the command  `gnome-panel` to my list of *Startup Applications*.

It works.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a .desktop file for `gnome-panel` in `.config/gnome-session/saved-session/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Panel
Comment=Launch other applications and provide various utilities to manage windows, show the time, etc.
Icon=gnome-panel
Exec=gnome-panel --sm-client-id 106bc2a27699861047128897536027503000000020640058
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-panel
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.30.2
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
#X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Panel
X-GNOME-Provides=panel
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-panel-2.0
X-GNOME-Autostart-startup-id=106bc2a27699861047128897536027503000000020640058
```

Might be worth looking at your saved-session to see if it is there at all.